# outputs wrong seed number

Tags: c++

So I have to make a program in c++ that returns the average of all the numbers in a 2d array, and it gets one case right. When the dimensions are 1 and 1, it returns 7 when the seed is 75. But any other case outputs 0. Is the seed statement wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

const int NUM_ROWS = 7;
const int NUM_COLS = 9;

double getArrayAverage(int myArray[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int rows, int cols);

int main() {
   const int NUM_ROWS = 7;
   const int NUM_COLS = 9;
   int seed;
   int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
   double num = 0;

   cin >> seed;

   srand(seed);

   for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
         array[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
         }
      } 

      num = getArrayAverage(array, NUM_ROWS, NUM_COLS);
      cout << num << endl;
      return 0;
   }

   double getArrayAverage(int array[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], int rows, int cols) {
      int sum = 0;
      double average = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            sum = sum + array[i][j];
            }
         }
         average = sum / (rows * cols);
         return average;

      }
```

Comment: The `seed()` statement isn't wrong, there seems to be another problem with your code. What did you observe when debugging it line by line?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it says when I run the debugger that "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'array' was corrupted. occurred" . I am using Visual Studio 2017. It is kind of new to me

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], in particular remove the manual input operation, unless that is actually necessary. Also make sure that the code is indented consistently, after all you want people to read it.

Comment: @JohnSmith You have a typo: `for (int j = 0; i < cols; i++) { ` should probably be `for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {`!

Comment: According to the observation of @πάνταῥεῖ `i` will be `NUM_COLS` (9) after leaving the inner loop first time. Before, it leaves it does e.g. `array[7][0] = rand() % 10 + 1;` and `array[8][0] = rand() % 10 + 1;` both are out of bound write accesses to `array`. Here, we are - corruption of stack around `array`. For educational purpose, you can reproduce this in your debugger before fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Three errors that I can quickly see

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
```

This error happens twice, be very careful when cutting and pasting code!

The other error is using integer division when you clearly want floating point division. In this statement

```
     average = sum / (rows * cols);
```

`sum` and `(rows * cols)` are both `int` values. So the division will be an integer division. In integer division the result is the integer obtained by truncating the result towrds zero. So 1/2 is 0, 8/3 is 2, 14/4 is 3 etc. In other words you lose the fractional part of the result in integer division.

To get floating point division and keep the fractions cast one of the `int` values to a `double`, e.g.

```
     average = (double)sum / (rows * cols);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure it out once looking through it.